# How to import a module within a module using Dynamic behaviour

Tags: typescript, nestjs

My problem is that I could not make dependency injection work properly when modules are nested.

Here is my scenario:

I have custom modules:

- Config -> no dependency
- Keycloak -> requires Config
- Auth -> requires Keycloak

My dynamic import for the Keycloak module works but it has a problem when I try to provide options from the Auth module. It is not able to find DI properly.

The code for the Keycloak module works just fine. My problem starts with the Auth service which needs to be dependent on the Keycloak module itself.

When I try to use it like this

```js
test('Auth module', async () => {
  const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
    imports: [
      AuthModule.forRootAsync({
        imports: [ConfigModule],
        useFactory: async (config: ConfigService) => ({
          roles: ['admin'],
          keycloakOptions: {
            baseUrl: config.get('KEYCLOAK_URL'),
          },
        }),
        inject: [ConfigService],
      }),
    ],
  }).compile();

  const auth = module.get(AuthService);

  expect(auth).toBeDefined();

  await expect(auth.login()).resolves.not.toThrow();
  await expect(auth.login()).resolves.toBe('aaa.bbb.ccc');
});
```

I get an error

```
Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the KEYCLOAK_OPTIONS (?). Please make sure that the argument "AUTH_OPTIONS" at index [0] is available in the KeycloakModule context.

Potential solutions:
- Is KeycloakModule a valid NestJS module?
- If "AUTH_OPTIONS" is a provider, is it part of the current KeycloakModule?
- If "AUTH_OPTIONS" is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within KeycloakModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing "AUTH_OPTIONS" */ ]
  })
```

I was kinda expected that when I do `inject: [Auth.Options]` it would inject that provider from the parent module but apparently it's not happening that way. What can I do to make it work?

Here is a full code available in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/nestjs-playground-forked-zwpjxm?workspaceId=85ddae6e-a669-47e1-931f-9208c70d7b9e&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu2m0ttp00063b6fqppmbf3j%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B47.812995245641844%252C52.187004754358156%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu2m0tto00023b6f9520nyt6%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu2m0ttp00043b6fcvrvx0m5%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu2m0ttp00053b6ffejxrdhc%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clu2m0tto00023b6f9520nyt6%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu2m0tto00023b6f9520nyt6%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%257D%252C%2522clu2m0ttp00053b6ffejxrdhc%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu2m0ttp00053b6ffejxrdhc%2522%257D%252C%2522clu2m0ttp00043b6fcvrvx0m5%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu2m0ttp00043b6fcvrvx0m5%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clu2m4qx8007p3b6ehjjbqk6g%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu2m4qx8007p3b6ehjjbqk6g%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clu2m4qz8007ydhev2gq53mqv%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D) (`src/module.spec.ts`)

P.S.

I also checked this document https://dev.to/nestjs/advanced-nestjs-how-to-build-completely-dynamic-nestjs-modules-1370 but could not apply to my use case :(